Construir Consulta atravez de chekbox
Hola como estan recientemente vi este ejemplo en un tutorial pero no he podido amoldarlo a lo que necesito, se trata de construir la consulta MYSQL seleccionando los chekbox que quiero en esa consulta, y hay una extra que es edad la cual es calculada. en este foro me enseñaron como hacerla en Mysql.. llevo esto.. ya le adicione las correcciones propuestas Mil gracias por responder... me han salvado
    <?php
//valor inicial de la cadena Consulta
//$Consulta = "SELECT * FROM filtros WHERE";
$estad=$_POST["estadotrabajador"];
// este campo para la edad------------
$edad=$_POST["edad"];
if($edad=="si"){
    $consulty=" ,fecha_nacimiento
       , YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) AS anio_nacimiento
       , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_nacimiento, CURDATE()) edad ";
}else{
    $consulty="";
}

$Consulta = "SELECT ";
//Pregunto si ha sido enviado el formulario , en este caso si el arreglo POST presenta el indice enviar que no es mas que el nombre del botón del formulario
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    //Mantengo esta línea que tenias
    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
    //Almaceno la longitud del arreglo para comparar posteriormente y para tomarlo como referencia en el ciclo for a continuación
    $length = count($_POST["estados"]); 
    //Recorro el arreglo pasado por el formulario con los valores de los checkbox que fueron marcados
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
         $Consulta .= " ".$_POST["estados"][$i]." ".(($i == $length-1)?"":" ,"); 
     }
    }
        $Consulta .= $consulty;
        $Consulta .= " FROM datos_archivo WHERE estadotrabajador='".$estad."'" ;
        
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Casillas</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="Post">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="nombre">
      Nombre
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="municipio"> 
    Municipio
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="cargo"> 
    Cargo
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="fecha_nacimiento"> 
    Fecha Nacimiento
    <input type="checkbox" name="estados[]" value="tiposanguineo"> 
    Tipo sanguineo</p>
    <p>
      <select name="estadotrabajador" id="estadotrabajador">
        <option value="activo">Activo</option>
        <option value="inactivo">Inactivo</option>
      </select>
      <input name="edad" type="checkbox" id="edad" value="si"> 
      Edad
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </p>
    
</form>
<br>
<?php echo $Consulta; ?>
</body>
</html>


No iteres toda la coleccion.. o agrega un if dentro que chequee el value y agregue el codigo que vos queres... no hay otra forma...

ya adicione como le hice los cambios, me tocaria revisar el campo edad ya que como no tengo un campo edad en la base de datos me toca hacerla calculada (pues esta va cambiando cada año...

y ahora cual seria el problema??

que me sirve todo menos cuando activo la casilla edad, el cual debe hacer el calculo en la linea mysql para hacer el calculo de la edad... al parecer mysql no admite esas funciones que pongo
if($edad=="si"){
$consulty=" AND fecha_nacimiento
, YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) AS anio_nacimiento
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_nacimiento, CURDATE()) edad";
}else{
$consulty="";
}

ese and no parece estar en el lugar correcto.. como queda el sql resultante?

cierto.. no lo lo habia notado.. ya le cambie de posicion.. me quedo asi  (ver edicion)

Y ahora, cual seria el problema?

Vas a tener 2 problemas posibles: 1. Si seleccionas edad y ningún estados (te va a sobrar una coma). 2. Si no selecciona nada (la consulta no va a traer ningun campo).
